# Trouble getting value of dynamically created textbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have  a webpage where the user inputs a number into a textbox and then that number of rows are created in a table with textboxes in each row with the id in the format of "id[I]" where I is the number assigned from the for loop used to add the textboxes. On form submit I'm trying to get the value of these textboxes. This is my form submit code to test things out.

```
$("#biopsyform").submit(function () {
    var site = $("#site[1]").attr("value");
    alert(site);
});
```

when I submit the form I get an alert of `undefined`

I've tried saying `var site = $("#site[1]#).val();` and get the same result.

When using chrome developer tools in the javascript debugger when I break before the alert, it shows the correct value for `$("#site[1]")` so I'm not quite sure what is going on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPEAN/3/) I'm getting an error in jsfiddle when I submit and I'm not sure why, I've never used jsfiddle. It could be part of my problem, it could be when I copied stuff over to jsfiddle, I don't know.

Comment: A jsFiddle would be great

Comment: I don't see your query `#site[1]`, I'm not sure if you know the meaning of `[]` which means you are looking for a html node with `site` id an attribute named `1`??? and if you know it would be grate to provide a jsfiddle DEMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping `[` and `]` with `\\`

```
var site = $("#site\\[1\\]").attr("value");

or

var site = $("#site\\[1\\]").val();
```

***[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kPEAN/5/)***

You were missing a `$` sign.

Comment: @downvoter - why downvoted? this works. doesn't it? please comment.

Comment: actually no one here has realized the real problem except you, when we use `[]` in our queries it means you are looking for an attribute and here adding `\\\` would prevent jquery to look fot attributes.

Comment: this gives me an unhandled exception

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure why this didn't work about 45 minutes ago, but now it does. But it does work now so thank you.

Comment: @user3064073 - glad it worked. I updated my answer with the updated DEMO. In your initial demo, `$` sign was missing.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the parent of the $("#site[1]").attr("value");

Example:

```
$("#parent").find("#site[1]").val();
```

Or any variations of that.

Comment: I've tried, `$(this)`, `$("#formname")`, `$("#tablename")` as the parent and no success for any of them.